# How can I find out whether or not micros(), delayMicroseconds() or the LCD library uses interrupts? (Arduino Uno platform)

Tags: atmega, arduino-uno

Where do I look to find code that signifies that it uses interrupts? I've gone through wiring.c in the subfolder of Arduino, but it only leads to the function.

The issue is that when I *enable* CTC mode for Timer/Comp0, the LCD prints out complete jibberish, but when I *disable* CTC mode, it works perfectly fine.

Here is the timer initialization code:

```
void timerCompare0_ini(void){                               // -Initialization of the Timer Compare 0
    TCCR0A  = 0;                                            // This regulates the menu navigation arrow to show where user is pointing                      
    TCCR0B  = 0;                                                              
    TCNT0   = 0;                                       
    OCR0B   = 256;
    // TCCR0A |= (1 << COM0B0) | (1 << COM0B1); 
    TCCR0A |= (1 << WGM01);                                   // -CTC mode
    TCCR0B |= ((1 << CS02) | (1 << CS00));                    // -1024 prescaler
    TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0B);                                  // -Enable timer compare interrupt

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*wiring.c* is good place. delay() uses micros() which depends on running timer0 and overflow interrupt. delayMicroseconds() does internal pause based on instructions. BTW But both method has bug because when watchdog is set shorter than requested delay it reboots CPU. I.e. you need implement own functions.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed towards micros() using TIMER0_OVF_vect. Further investigation leads me to believe that modifying the the MODE that micros() requires will mess up that function, therefore messing up other functions. Am I correct to say that that function requires the timer to be in FAST PWM (mode 3 in datasheet)? And seeing that delayMicroseconds() does not need an interrupt (using NOPs), changing the MODE of the Timer0 interrupt should not affect this function right?

Comment: Yes, delayMicroseconds() depends only on crystal frequency. I personally did not modify timer0 and rather use another one not to fall in mode issues for working Arduino timing code (even I try to avoid as much as possible from Arduino stuff). You can use probably another mode but it requires precise datasheet reading because there are minor differences between modes. But I think I use for the second timing also a FAST PWM mode.